# How to keep SoapUI request settings in a single place?

Tags: web-services, testing, soapui

I have created a project with a bunch of test steps of type `HTTP Request`. Each http request uses `Basic Authorization`. When I specify username/password values in `Auth` request tab as show in the image below, all works fine.
[image]
How to keep these `settings in a single place per a project` and so that do not have to change for each request if required to change the credentials?

I tried [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) feature, and it doesn't work in `Auth` tab. **UPDATE #3:** It works!

Actually I have a **solution**: project file is a readable XML, so it is easy to replace username/password values (or service URL... everything) in external text editor. Hope for a better way.

**UPDATE #1:** Accessible authorization types for a HTTP request:
[image]

**UPDATE #2:** Free SoapUI 5.2.1 is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are right. It would be very easy for maintenance of the `SoapUI` project if the *properties are used*. 
In your case, use of *`project level custom properties`* would be appropriate as per the need.

**You could do below to achieve the same:**

1. Select the project.
2. Left side, you see the properties in the down.
3. Select custom properties tab.
4. Define two properties for username and password respective along with values. say, USERNAME, and PASSCODE.
5. Now, in the each step, replace with username and password with `${#Project#USERNAME}, ${#Project#PASSOCDE}` respectively. This will be one time effort.

*You can see in screen shot below that the response on the right side when the request is sent after using `property expansion` for authorization.*

[image: Defining project properties and using them in authorization]

Note that you might notice there is a difference in the screen shot when compared with your for Authorization, because of the `SoapUI` version is 4.5.1. However, that should not be any cause of concern.

Once the changes are done, save the project. Now onwards, it will be `single place` to just modify user credentials. Of course, you can also change these values from xml file as well like you mentioned.

Apart from the above, it is even possible to override the project property values without even modifying in the soapui-project xml file if you run the SoapUI project from command prompt using `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat or .sh` utility, with the help of `-P` option, as mentioned below.

```
cmd > cd %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin
cmd > testrunner.bat -PUSERNAME=user1 -PPASSCODE=user1passcode -R"Project Report" c:\projects\my-soapui-project.xml
```

For complete command-line options to run soaui project, please visit [here](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

**UPDATE:** Looks there is confusion cased because of SoapUI 4.5.1 screen shot. But the above works in SoapUI-5.x version as well.

Make sure you have set the 
`File -> Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Authenticate Preemptively`  **(check box)is checked (adds authentication information to out going request)** and save the preferences.

Below is `specific for SoapUI-5.x` setting.
In the `Authorization -> Basic`[as you mentioned in the screen shot], set the property expansion as mentioned above for credentials. Also, Pre-emptive auth: `Use global preference` radio checked.

Comment: As I said I tried and it didn't work. One distinction is I don't have "Global HTTP settings" authorization (added a screenshot to the question) so I tested it for the "Basic" auth type. How you got this "Global HTTP settings" authorization type?

Comment: My fault, I didn't specified the version. I use the up-to-date open source SoapUI 5.2.1. Are you use free or NG version?

Comment: Just tried it on SoapUI 5.2.1 Open Source edition, and it does work well which I did mention in the answer saying that is not cause of concern. Can you post your raw request please? or check if you can see the credentions going or not in the raw request? Otherwise, check the preferences `Authenticate Preemptively` is checked under `HTTP Settings` and save the preferences.

Comment: OK, I tried ONCE AGAIN and now project-scope parameters (for example `${#Project#USERNAME}`) are working in `Auth` tab! And these parameters are **case-sencitive**, I assume it is the point I missed. Thanks!

Comment: My previous comment was unclear: `#Project` statement only is case-sencitive. If I try to access a property with `#project#` prefix it doesn't work. However, if `USERNAME` property is defined, it can be accessed as `${#Project#username}`!

Comment: Yes  case sensitive. You can see in the screen shot,  how the properties are defined and how they are used.