# Setting Pre-emptive AuthType for Test Step in SoapUI in script

Tags: authentication, groovy, authorization, soapui

In SoapUI 5.0.0 I am trying to set the Pre-emptive auth value (Global settings or Pre-emptive) for a Test Request step via scripting. This is for Basic Authorization.

I am able to set the Username, Password, and Domain by script but not the AuthType

```
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["MyTestRequest"]
testStep.setPropertyValue("Username", "myusername")
testStep.setPropertyValue("Password", "mypassword")
testStep.setPropertyValue("Domain", "domain-name")

testStep.setPropertyValue("AuthType", "Preemptive")
```

Comment: please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205373/how-to-keep-soapui-request-settings-in-a-single-place/35214165#35214165) helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rao - i had a look - couldn't see where you can change the setting via scripting. Reason for this being that i want to dynamically switch the endpoints of the same test step request where one endpoint requires authorization and the other doesn't.

Comment: I understand that you wanted to have flexibility around credentials and endpoint which you may do it from script. However, `AuthType` is something which is going to be fixed. So you set it one as mentioned in the earlier link. You should be fine even if you do not set using script. Otherwise, provide more on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for that - I see that a test request that doesn't require authorization will still work even if you submit a request with pre-emptive authorization - so I will just have to leave the AuthType value set as it is via the GUI. Thank you.

Comment: Though you agreed to what I said, it did encourage me to find how to do it. Hence, added the answer below, check it out please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am putting the required code down here, how one can set the **AuthType -> Pre-emptive** through the code.

*Credentials, Endpoint* can be a valid point of concern that they will change depending on the environment like *Dev, QA, or Production* etc.,

However, `AuthType` does not fall in the above category as it is fixed across the environments once it is set, do not have to touch it.

**Script Below**

```groovy
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.HttpSettings
//To enable Pre-emptive, set it true. Set it to false otherwise
SoapUI.getSettings().setBoolean(HttpSettings.AUTHENTICATE_PREEMPTIVELY, true)
SoapUI.saveSettings()
```

*How do you check once the above script is run?*

Go to(using menu) `File -> Preferences -> Http Settings -> Authenticate Preemptively` should be having *check box tick marked* when it is `true`. Check box `unticked` when it is set to `false`, obviously.

Another way is to check when it is set to true is that make a web service call. Then go to `Raw Request` tab of the *request editor*. You should be able to see the authentication is added into the request. Of course, when you get the valid response, that it self tells that above code actually did what is it is intended to do.

Comment: Thanks @Rao, that worked. I also spent a few hours trying to research if there was some Java trickery that could set the AuthType using _com.eviware.soapui.config.CredentialsConfig.AuthType_ but no joy.